# Move carousel caption outside carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to move the caption outside the coursel towards the left side but the problem it's not working.  Whenever it moves outside its parent container it stops showing. Can somebody please help me out. Here is a JS bin link --> [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com/gikatihesu/edit?html,output)

It would be great if anyone could help me out. Thanks

```
OS: Mac

Browser: Chrome 74.0

Bootstrap version: 4.1.1
```

Comment: your JSBIN link is broken

Comment: @SASSY_ROG please check now

Answer (score 0):

The element with the class `carousel-inner` has the following declaration set by Bootstrap: `overflow: hidden`. It prevents any of its children elements placed outside its padding-box to be visible.

To prevent that behaviour, you need to override that declaration with: `overflow: visible`. Then, to prevent the slides from being shown when moving, you need to wrap the carousel inside another element, add some padding at the bottom of that element to allow the caption to be visible (`60px` for instance), and set its `overflow` property to `hidden`.

So you need to add the following code to your CSS:

```css
.carousel-container {
  padding: 0 0 60px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <!-- The code of the carousel -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this does solves the problem but then I can see the image that is sliding out.

Comment: Right, I couldn't see that on your JSBin as the carousel takes up the whole width. I edited my answer to prevent that issue, I hope that works for you.

Comment: the problem still persists. Let me share a screencast

Comment: It is hard to say what is going wrong here, but maybe the container element is larger in width than the carousel element? It should be the exact same width as the carousel element and have no horizontal padding. I can't reproduce the problem, it works fine in JSBin with the changes from my answer: https://jsbin.com/siyahukiji/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Set the caption relative to the image:

```
  .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absoloute;
  }


  .carousel-caption {
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
```

Comment: this still doesn't solve the problem. The parent container still does not allow me to move the caption outside the container

Comment: In that case, add `position: absolute` to the parent container, and switch `.carousel-inner img` to `position: relative`